# Collapse Side-nav on click responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I adjust a bougth onepage-template for my wishes, but unfortunately I'm not good in JS.
So, I have a side menu, which stays in desktop version. But on mobile/tablet-version I have a toggle menu icon. On click the menu opens, but when I click on a navigation-point the menu stays open. I would like to have it closed after clicking.
Thanks for your help

```
<aside class="nav_sidebar">
        <div class="menu_wrapper">
            <div class="header_top">

                <div class="head_img_wrap">
                    <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="Images">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="main_menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home"><p>Home</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about"><p>Über mich</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#service"><p>services</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#portfolio"><p>portfolio</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog"><p>blog</p></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"><p>kontakt</p></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </aside><!-- end header -->

    <!-- menu toggler -->
    <div class="menu_toggler">
        <span class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </div>
    <!-- menu toggler -->
```

```
// Mobile menu css
    var $menu_toggler = $('.menu_toggler'),
        $menuSidebar = $('aside.nav_sidebar');

    $menu_toggler.on('click',function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $menuSidebar.toggleClass('open');
    });
    if(windowWidth < 768){$menuSidebar.toggleClass('shrinked');}

    // collapsible menu css
    $('.toggle_icon span').on('click', function () {
        $menuSidebar.toggleClass('collapse');

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
$menuSidebar.on("mouseup", function() {
    $menuSidebar.removeClass('open');
});
```

When something is clicked in the sidebar, it will trigger the mouseup event

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried this:

```
// Mobile menu css
    var $menu_toggler = $('.menu_toggler'),
        $menuSidebar = $('aside.nav_sidebar');

    $menu_toggler.on('click',function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $menuSidebar.toggleClass('open');
    });
    if(windowWidth < 768){$menuSidebar.toggleClass('shrinked');}

    // collapsible menu css
    $menuSidebar.on("mouseup", function() {
    $menuSidebar.removeClass('open');
        });
```

and it works but the toggle icon stays in the middle after closing. It should go back on the left side. Someone help for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the open class on both the menu and the button, so:

```
$menuSidebar.on("mouseup", function() {
    $menuSidebar.removeClass("open");
    $menu_toggler.removeClass("open");
});
```